# How to add components conditionally to the JSF component tree based on value which is available at render time?

Tags: performance, jsf, datatable, components, jsf-2.2

How can I choose conditionally the type of the html input in a standard JSF dataTable without the overhead of the unrendered components? I have a solution but this is not good enough for me.

Example test bean:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Map<Descriptor, Object> values = new HashMap<>();

    public TestBean() {
        values.put(new Descriptor("Integer value", "Integer"), 10);
        values.put(new Descriptor("String value", "String"), "example string");
        values.put(new Descriptor("Boolean value", "Boolean"), Boolean.TRUE);
    }

    public Map<Descriptor, Object> getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    public class Descriptor implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private String name;
        private String type;

        public Descriptor(String name, String type) {
            this.name = name;
            this.type = type;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) {
                return true;
            }
            if (o == null || !TestBean.class.equals(o.getClass())) {
                return false;
            }
            Descriptor other = (Descriptor) o;
            return Objects.equals(name, other.name) &&
                    Objects.equals(type, other.type);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(name, type);
        }
    }
}
```

Example test.xhtml part1:

```
<!-- Works -->
<h:dataTable value="#{testBean.values.keySet()}" var="valueKey">
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Key</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{valueKey.name}"/>
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Value</f:facet>
        <h:inputText pt:type="number" pt:step="1" converter="javax.faces.Integer"
                     value="#{testBean.values[valueKey]}" rendered="#{valueKey.type eq 'Integer'}"/>
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{testBean.values[valueKey]}" rendered="#{valueKey.type eq 'Boolean'}"/>
        <h:inputTextarea value="#{testBean.values[valueKey]}"
                         rendered="#{valueKey.type ne 'Integer' and valueKey.type ne 'Boolean'}"/>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

This way everything works correctly but I triple the number of components for a single input. (The unrendered components still added to the component tree.) This is not acceptable because I have to work with a large dataset. In case of huge amount of entries the response time is very slow. So i looking for another way, like the example below:

Example test.xhtml part2:

```
<!-- Doesn't work -->
<h:dataTable value="#{testBean.values.keySet()}" var="valueKey">
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Key</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{valueKey.name}"/>
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Value</f:facet>
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="#{valueKey.type eq 'Integer'}">
                <h:inputText pt:type="number" pt:step="1" converter="javax.faces.Integer"
                             value="#{testBean.values[valueKey]}"/>
            </c:when>
            <c:when test="#{valueKey.type eq 'Boolean'}">
                <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{testBean.values[valueKey]}"/>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <h:inputTextarea value="#{testBean.values[valueKey]}"/>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

This would be great but the value of the test attribute is null at the time of the view build.

**Is there any workaround to reduce the number of components when I need a switch statement inside a dataTable?** In other words: How can I achieve the result of the first example without the additional (unrendered) components in the component tree?

(I work with Mojarra 2.2.8-17)

Comment: How many lines do you want to load in the same page? Have you done any benchmark with the `rendered` attribute, for, say, 1000 lines? Still, I think it is more UX friendly to display an smaller amount of lines an implement pagination. That way you avoid the overhead you mention and also other kind of issues (imagine the user inputs 1000 values and, when sending them, the session gets expired, so he has to login again and redo all the work..)

Comment: I want to load more than 1000 lines. On the client side the pagination solved with javascript. I know I can do this with lazy loading but it adds much more complexity. Actually I want to use a third party dataTable (from Bootsfaces) and there is no lazy loading support in this implementation. That's why I looking for something else. Without lazy loading I can search in the table and sort the rows. With a lazy loading solution this is a difficult thing.

Comment: Lazy loading is related to how your data is retrieved in your managed bean from a service which might rely in a DB or an API. The problem you state above seems to have nothing to do with that (you say you want to improve JSF rendering the page itself). I got some primefaces datatables in production without lazy loading displaying more than 15K items. All the items are loaded from DB in a single query and stored in the managed bean, the page takes less than 3 secs to get displayed. However, I use pagination (25 per page) and let the user filter by any field in the table.

Comment: In term of lazy loading I mean client side lazy loading. For example I send back only the first 100 lines and if the user steps forward with the paginator the client sends an ajax request and It updates the table.

Comment: I made a measurement with 5000 records. I compared the ui:repeat loop with the rendered attributes to the c:forEach loop with c:choose. The result is interesting. In case of ui:repeat the response time was 2.88 seconds but in case of c:forEach the response time was 20.67 seconds.

Comment: Could you post the whole test case? It would be intersting for comparison. You could edit your question to add them.